# Restore Bluetooth on Resume

Tags: linux, bluetooth, suspend

Bluetooth works fine until I suspend. When I restart it won't turn on again.

On resume hcitool lists no devices

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
```

How do I restore bluetooth on resume.
I'm using Fedora 23 with Gnome 3.18 on a Lenovo G50-70.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was with [rfkill](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/rfkill). Rfkill is responsible for radio devices and their state on startup and battery power etc.

```
$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

The trick was to edit `/etc/default/tlp`. I needed to set:

```
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=1
```

Thanks and credit to [Major Hayden](https://major.io/2015/07/19/restoring-wireless-and-bluetooth-state-after-reboot-in-fedora-22/).